# How can I insert a calendar component into an Angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-framework

I am absolutly new in **Angular 2** and I have a doubt: I simply have to insert a calendar into a page where the user can add events.

Something like this: https://angular-material-calendar.bradb.net/

I am not understanding if this **angular material calendar** project is for Angular 2 or for the old AngularJS.

I also don't know if it is a good component or if exist something better.

What do you suggest me to complete this task?

**EDIT-1:** I also found this **PrimeNG** calendar component: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

Can be an idea or am I adding another layer of complexity to my app?

Comment: this is for angularjs ( 1.x )

Comment: @brijmcq ok I added an edit at the end of my original post about PrimeNG

Comment: The inserting is no problem, but you should know that you have to store the events somewhere. Are you already working with a database in your project ? Oh and the one you searched is for Angular 1. If its named angularjs (It´s Angular 1.x).

Comment: @Doomenik I am mainly a Java back end developer. I am study Angular 2 (ops...Angular 4) because I want to do some experiment. The backend with REST API is not a problem for me

Comment: Perfect, you could use https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar but there tons more out there. It will be easy for you, angular does the most frontend stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [component](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink) based from full-calendar. You didn't include your use cases but I think ng2-fullcalendar may have all you need.

PrimeNG is also good and is also based from full-calendar.

I think that this is a necessary complexity because implementing a scheduler can be difficult ( at least for me )

Comment: This seems very good for me. The only doubs is: can I insert an event simply selecting a day and clicking with the mouse on a specific day?

Comment: If that's the case, PrimeNG has that feature.  With ng2-fullcalendar, I'm afraid you need to implement it yourself

Comment: Yeah PrimeNG seems to be very good for my pourpose. Only a last doubt. Using PrimeNG do you think that I cam nodify it do add some other information to the scheduled event? (For example a description and not only the event name)

Comment: Yes it is possible. But you may need to get your hands dirty. You can see the source code . Additional info https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/, 
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/src/app/showcase/components/schedule

Answer (score 0):

i request to use angular-calendar ,refer this npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar